# How to show error message without using Toast

Tags: android, error-handling, android-toast

Can I show any other way to error message not using `toast message`. Please help me? 
and i don't want to display the popup also..

Comment: also can use Coustem Toast and Dialog in android to show error message

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647465/facebook-app-type-no-internet-connection-message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647465/facebook-app-type-no-internet-connection-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `setError()` method and u can use like `edittext.setError("ur message",icon);`

Answer (score 2):

Use Animation, onclick of edittext(if its empty)

```
    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoginActivity.this,
            R.anim.shake);
    editTextId.startAnimation(shake);
```

Create folder anim in res

Add file shake.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7"
android:toXDelta="10" />
```

file cycle_7.xml

```
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:cycles="7" />
```